# Как в SQL запросе в качестве имени колонки сконкатенировать результат другого запроса

Tags: sql, postgresql9.5

Имеются например 2 таблицы A и B

таблица A

```
ID_A(UUID) | CH1(INTEGER) | CH2(INTEGER)| ... | CH32(INTEGER) |
```

таблица B

```
ID_B(UUID) | ID_A(UUID) | CH(SMALLINT) |
```

Мне нужно одним запросом получить значение CHN(вместо N числа от 1 до 32) из таблицы A

```
SELECT CHN 
  FROM A 
 WHERE id_A = 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'
```

причём N является результатом запроса из таблицы B

```
SELECT CH 
  FROM B 
 WHERE ID_B = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
   AND ID_A = 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'
```

Каким образом получить значение из таблицы B и сконкатенировать со строкой запроса к таблице A Например, чтобы это выглядело примерно так

```
SELECT CH + '(SELECT CH FROM B WHERE ID_B = '00000000-0000-0000-000000000000000' AND ID_A = 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF')' 
 FROM A WHERE id_A = 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'
```

Comment: Формально задача решается использованием динамического SQL. См. напр. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN Но лучше нормализовать данные первой таблицы.

Comment: 1. Конкатенация в PostgreSQL - || , а не +.
2. Подзапрос не нужно брать в кавычки.
3. Число N преобразовать к строке.
4. Подзапрос должен возвращать одну строку для каждой строки основного запроса.

Comment: Akina Каким образом можно нормализовать таблицу и что подразумевается под "нормализовать"?

Comment: Sergey Moiseenko Как это осуществить в моём случае?

Comment: Попробуйте так для начала:

SELECT cast(CH as varchar(5)) || (SELECT cast(CH as varchar(5)) FROM B WHERE ID_B = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND ID_A = 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF') FROM A WHERE id_A = 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko Невозможно в SQL имена колонок генерить из выражений, то что вы написали сконкатенирует _значения_ колонки CH (если бы она была) и подзапроса. потому что все имена в любом SQL запросе заданы сразу, а запрос работает только со значениями, если бы можно было бы работать с именами для этого бы сделали бы отдельный синтаксис, по которому можно было бы отличить от обычной работы sql

Comment: @Mike, значит я неправильно понял задачу.

Comment: @Mike Что же мне делать в такой ситуации?

Comment: Евгений, я запутался. У вас в структуре таблицы `B` нет колонки `ID_A`, однако вы к ней обращаетесь, что это символизирует ? Пока выглядит так, что динамический SQL не нужен и все решается простым join и конкатенацией. Добавьте в вопрос пример пару строчек значений для каждой таблицы и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: @lDrakonl Извиняюсь поменял SN_A на ID_A. Хотя это не имеет значения, вопрос не в этом

Comment: Не был уверен, что правильно понял связь таблиц для того, чтобы поменять подзапрос на join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL не рассчитан на работу с данными, представленными в таком виде. Наиболее правильным подходом было бы нормализовать структуру (сейчас нарушена [первая нормальная форма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)). Т.е. одну строку первой таблицы превратить в несколько строк, со структурой `(ID_A, CH_NUM, VALUE)` и тогда запрос выглядел бы как `select value from A where ID_A=X and CH_NUM=(select ...)`.

При сохранении текущей структуры есть только 2 пути: Первый - работать с динамическим SQL, т.е. заранее получать номер нужной колонки и формировать запрос в таблицу A как текст. Выполнять можно либо на клиенте, либо в хранимой процедуре.

Второй путь - перечислить все колонки и выбирать *значение* нужной, чем то вроде такого:

```
SELECT (ARRAY[CH1,CH2,CH3,...,CH32])
        [ (SELECT CH FROM B ....) ]
  FROM A 
 WHERE id_A = 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'
```

Тут мы преобразуем список колонок в массив значений и берем требуемый элемент этого массива. В принципе в качестве быстрой (но неполной) нормализации вместо колонок CH1-CH32 можно было бы завести одну колонку типа ARRAY.

Answer (score 1):

Можно избавиться от подзапроса используя `join` и брать нужное поле используя `case when then..`

```
SELECT case wnen b.ch='1' then a.CH1 
            wnen b.ch='2' then a.CH2       
       ...
            wnen b.ch='32' then a.CH32 
       else null end
FROM  A 
INNER JOIN B 
ON    A.id_A = B.id_a
AND   b.id_b='00000000-0000-0000-000000000000000'
WHERE A.id_a='FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'
```